# Find unique occurrence of _ in a given string

Tags: c#

First lets paste a code and then I will tell you what is my requirement..

```
void Main()
{
    String someString = "Fill ________ and ______ this";
    char someChar = '_';
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < someString.Length; i++)
    {
        if (someString[i] == someChar)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here in this snippet I have 2 placeholder denoted with _.
if `_` occurs more than 2 times at a time , then this considered to be a placeholder in that string.

### Input

1. There is a single _ here.

### Output

0

### Input

2. There are 2 single _ and _ here.

### Output

0

### Input

3. There 1 double __ here.

### Output

0

### Input

4. There are 1 tripple ___ here.

   ### Output

1

### Input

5. There are 1 single _ , 1 double __ and 1 tripple ___ here.

   ### Output

1

### Input

Fill ________ and ______ this

### Output

2

Comment: Why don't you just search if the string Contains a triple underscore?

Comment: Um, what was the question?

Comment: You could use a regular expression to solve this, it's quite straightforward to write a pattern to match all "3 or more consecutive underscores"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notwithstanding "now you have two problems", this can be solved with a [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions). `_{3,}` is a pattern matching a series of at least three underscores, so:

```
Regex.Matches("Fill ________ and ______ this", "_{3,}").Count

2

Regex.Matches("There are 1 single _ , 1 double __ and 1 tripple ___ here.", "_{3,}").Count

1
```